# Django: Why does my code let the user create a new account with an email address that has already been taken?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

When I remove the following

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
```

it recognizes if user uses a taken email address when signing up and shows user a sign up error. However the below code does not throw any error on email address taken. How can I fix this?

```
def signup(request):
 if request.method == "POST":
    # User has info and wants an account now!
    if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
            email = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': 'Email and or username has already been taken'})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], email=request.POST['email'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('homepage')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error': 'Passwords must match'})
 # User wants to enter info
 return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

Comment: If the `User` doesn't exist... you enter the exception block and create the user without any form of checking the email address...

Comment: You should put `unique=True` on the email field if you want to ensure the supplied email address isn't already taken.

Comment: @markwalker_ might nicer option - that way the DB enforces it for you :) (Does mean a custom User model though)

Comment: @JonClements why does `email = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])` not run and how could I modify my code to make it run

Comment: @Padoga because where the username doesn't exist, it raises `User.DoesNotExist`, leaves the try block and goes straight to your `except` block where you don't check if the email exists already...

Comment: @JonClements thanks, any suggestion for doing this without modifying db. I tried to create a second try except block below it to check email with no luck. Modified the second except to have the code above to create user, and changed the first except to just have pass.

Comment: Can your check not just be `if User.objects.filter(Q(username=request.POST['username']) | Q(email=request.POST['email'])).exists()`...

Comment: Thanks @JonClements that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `except User.DoesNotExist:` by `except ObjectDoesNotExist:`. 
See the django definition of get() using [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get).

But before, you need to import exception as well :

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
```